# Client certificate authentication on IIS 8 - 401.1 Unauthorized

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8, client-certificates, http-status-code-401

We are developing ASP.NET application and we need to use Client Certificate Authentication on IIS 8.

I followed guides to setup SSL and Client Certification authentication. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/02/12/how-to-configure-iis-client-certificate-mapping-authentication-for-iis7/
and
https://blogs.iis.net/rlucero/iis-7-walkthrough-one-to-one-client-certificate-mapping-configuration

I've setup client certificate and added one-to-one mapping to map it to local administator account (once it works, i will change it to more resticted user).

I validated that both server and client certificate are valid and trusted on server and on clinet. So there is no problem with certification authority.

When i try to acces the web page i am promted to choose client certificate. When i confirm selected certificate i allways get 401.1 result: Unauthorized.

I think that it can be related with that in IIS Authentication settings i disabled all authentication types. When i enable Windows Authentication, it seems to work - I am prompted to select certificate and when i confirm selected certificate, i am prompted for username and password and then page is displayed correctly. Of course i do not want user to enter windows user name and password.

PS: Error log file from IIS is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/pe8qwxpgilr347l/fr000156.xml?dl=0

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i needed to install and activate "client certificate mapping authentication" in Windows Server Manager "Roles and Features" and the IIS configuration editor here: `system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication`